# NodeJS Queuing Asynchronous Functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, queue

I am working on a NodeJS function that has a series of asynchronous tasks that it needs to run.

I read in an array of `tasks` pulled from the database, and each `task` has a 'runFrequency'property.

**example**:

```
    var tasks: [
        task1: {
            type: doSomething,
            ...,
            runFrequency: 10    // Needs to run every 10 seconds.
        },
        task2: {
            type: doSomethingElse,
            ...,
            runFrequency: 30    // Needs to run every 30 seconds.
        },
        task3: {
            type: doSomething,
            ...,
            runFrequency: 10
        }
    ];
```

I need to call a `processTask()` function to run each task every `runFrequency` settings, but only run one task at a time. (the 10 second runFrequency is just a goal, it doesn't need to be exactly 10 seconds).

**example**

```
    12:00:00: processTask(task1);
    12:00:02: task1 completes, task1 scheduled to run again at 12:00:12,
    12:00:02: processTask(task2);
    12:00:05: task2 completes, task2 scheduled to run again at 12:00:35,
    12:00:05: processTask(task3);
    12:00:10: task3 completes, task3 scheduled to run again at 12:00:20,

    // all tasks finished, next task isn't scheduled to start until 12:00:12,

    12:00:12: processTask(task1);
    12:00:25: task1 completes, task1 scheduled to run again at 12:00:35, 
    12:00:25: task2 was scheduled to start at 12:00:20, it's the next task in the queue so it needs to be run now.
```

What would be the best way of setting up this sort of 'task queue' in NodeJS?

I've looked into Kue and Redis, but I'm not sure if this is exactly what I want.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a predetermined set of tasks that you want to schedule, you can just iterate over them and set intervals.

```
'use strict';
let tasks = [
    {
        name: 'Check StackOverflow',
        frequency: 1,
        taskFn: () => console.log('Checking StackOverflow...')
    },
    {
        name: 'Check Email',
        frequency: 3,
        taskFn: () => console.log('Checking email...')
    },
    {
        name: 'Download the Internet!',
        frequency: 5,
        taskFn: () => console.log('Downloading the internet')
    }
];

for (let task of tasks) {
    console.log(`Scheduling ${task.name}`);
    setInterval(task.taskFn, task.frequency * 1000);
}
```